# strpos fails to filter the keyword

Tags: php, strpos

From given url, I want to check whether it contains `//t.co` or `twitter.com`. If yes then skip it and while loop should continue.

```
if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $tweet, $url)) {
                preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $tweet, $urls);
                foreach ($urls[0] as $url) {
                echo "Tiny url :  {$url}<br>";
                $full = MyURLDecode($url);
                echo "Full url : $full<br>";
                if (strpos($full, '//t.co') === true)                   
                    continue;   
                if (strpos($full, '//twitter.com') === true)                    
                continue;
                else if (strpos($full, '//bit.ly') !== true)                    
                    $full = MyURLDecode($full);
                }
```

But though url contains above keyword it does not get skipped, what strpos fails? what is alternative for this?

Comment: Change your code, like so: http://pastie.org/8606363

Comment: Shouldn't that be an answer, not a comment?

Answer (score 1):

`strpos()` **never returns true**.either it will return the `position` when mathed or will return `false` when match is not found.

[Read Here](https://www.php.net/function.strpos)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
strpos($full, '//t.co') === true
```

as

```
 if(strpos($full, '//t.co') !== false)
```